# How to convert pcks12 certificate string, which was taken from azure key vault in docker container, to pem format?

Tags: docker, ssl, x509certificate, azure-keyvault, pkcs#12

I use for taking a certificate in a docker container via managed identity like described in Microsoft docs here (Example 1): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-managed-identity#example-1-use-a-user-assigned-identity-to-access-azure-key-vault

When it was a certificate in pem format output of the command:

```
curl https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/SampleSecret/?api-version=2016-10-01 -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"
```

Was like:

> {"value":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE
> KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDBkelEEzvwXiaW\nX4sPt052w/5tahn6OAy+lasH4Lq1xvU/G+z9Ra0rBs2NGhPr7smu8iAxACfr74I5\nCHENM4kvmM{too
> many symbols}KkrjDMmf5Om\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n-----BEGIN
> CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDMDCCAhigAw{too many symbols}4GMgUQ==\n-----END
> CERTIFICATE-----\n","contentType":"application/x-pem-file","id":"myid","managed":true,"attributes":{"enabled":true,"nbf":1600276258,"exp":1631812858,"created":1600276858,"updated":1600276858,"recoveryLevel":"Recoverable+Purgeable"},"kid":"https://cert_url"}

And parse it to cert.pem and private_key.pem files is easy.

But if it is pcks12 format output is just like one string:

> {"value":"MIIKPAIBAzCCCfwGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCCe0EggnpMIIJ5TCCBhYGCSqGSIb3DQEHA{only
> many
> symbols}8O3VaP5TOUaZMQ=","contentType":"application/x-pkcs12","id":"myid","managed":true,"attributes":{"enabled":true,"nbf":1600275456,"exp":1631812056,"created":1600276056,"updated":1600276056,"recoveryLevel":"Recoverable+Purgeable"},"kid":"https://cert_url"}

So I can't convert that string to cert.pem and private_key.pem files like was explained above.

I put in file cert.cer value via:

```
curl https://testigorcert.vault.azure.net/secrets/SampleSecret/?api-version=2016-10-01 -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" | jq '.value' > cert.cer
```

And tried command like:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.cer -out cert.pem -nodes
```

Error:

> 139876006393152:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding
> routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1130:
> 139876006393152:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding
> routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1
> error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:290:Type=PKCS12

Tried:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.cer -nocerts -nodes -out key.pem
```

Error:

> 140021099644224:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding
> routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1130:
> 140021099644224:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding
> routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1
> error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:290:Type=PKCS12

Tried:

```
openssl x509 -in cert.cer -text
```

Error:

> 139665046693184:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start
> line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

So. How can I convert this value of pkcs12 certificate format to two files cert.pem and private_key.pem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in encoding of downloaded string, because curl get a .pfx string, BUT in ascii coding (should be in base64). So I just use another way (Example 2):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-managed-identity#example-2-use-a-system-assigned-identity-to-access-azure-key-vault

Where I just download certificate .pfx via command:

```
az keyvault secret download --file cert.pfx --name {cert_name} --vault-name {vault_name} -e base64
```

And then convert to two needed files by:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -nocerts -out key.rsa -nodes -passin pass:
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.crt -passin pass:
```

Answer (score 0):

That another (best) option to convert cert to base 64 format by an appropriate command like:

```
token=$(curl 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fvault.azure.net' -H Metadata:true | jq -r '.access_token')

curl https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mycert/?api-version=2016-10-01 -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" | 
jq -r ".value" | base64 -d | openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out /etc/ssl/private-key.pem -nodes -passin pass:

curl https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mycert/?api-version=2016-10-01 -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" | 
jq -r ".value" | base64 -d | openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -out /etc/ssl/cert.pem -passin pass:
```